# dropping duplicate foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have about 100 tables where all of them have duplicate foreign key constraints on them.

Is there a way that I could get rid of it? Is there a query that could give me all duplicate keys in it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm using this T-SQL script here to detect potentially duplicate FK constraints - and it also produces the necessary `ALTER TABLE...DROP CONSTRAINT` statements in the last of the output columns.

You cannot reliably automatically detect and pick which of multiple FK constraints to drop - so you're basically left to detect them and then manually pick which ones to drop (using that drop statement produced by my query).

```
;WITH FKData AS
(
    SELECT  
        fk.parent_object_id,
        fkc.parent_column_id,
        fk.referenced_object_id,
        fkc.referenced_column_id,
        FKCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
         sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
         sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    GROUP BY 
         fk.parent_object_id, fkc.parent_column_id, fk.referenced_object_id, fkc.referenced_column_id
    HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1
),
DuplicateFK AS
(
    SELECT  
        FKName = fk.Name,
            ParentSchema = s1.Name,
        ParentTable = t1.Name,
        ParentColumn = c1.Name,
        ReferencedTable = t2.Name,
        ReferencedColumn = c2.Name 
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        FKData f ON fk.parent_object_id = f.parent_object_id 
                 AND fk.referenced_object_id = f.referenced_object_id 
                 AND fkc.parent_column_id = f.parent_column_id
                 AND fkc.referenced_column_id = f.referenced_column_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t1 ON f.parent_object_id = t1.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns c1 ON f.parent_object_id = c1.object_id AND f.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s1 ON t1.schema_id = s1.schema_id   
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t2 ON f.referenced_object_id = t2.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns c2 ON f.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id AND f.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
)
SELECT
    FKName,
    ParentSchema, ParentTable, ParentColumn, 
    ReferencedTable, ReferencedColumn,
    DropStmt = 'ALTER TABLE ' + ParentSchema + '.' + ParentTable + 
               ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FKName
FROM 
    DuplicateFK
```

Comment: is there a way we could get the schema name too? since there are few which doesn't belong to dbo schema.

Comment: @Peter: **SURE!** updated my response to include the parent schema (you could get the referenced schema, too, if needed - but you don't need that for the DROP statement)

Comment: Such an awesome query!  I added a small edit to add a ranking so that the DropStmt column only populates for row 2+ of same FK (thus can run the entire column and skip picking and choosing).

Comment: My apologies.  I don't in any way want to even seem like I am taking credit for something whose brainpower was not my own, which is what making a new response off OP seems like.  I am not sure what is meant by posting a response extending yours, so I will drop it rather than step on toes.  Thank you again for awesome query.

Answer (score 4):

This removes the most recently created duplicates

```
;WITH fkeys AS (
SELECT  f.object_id ,
        f.name ,
        f.parent_object_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.column_names ORDER BY f.create_date,f.[object_id]) AS RowNum
FROM    sys.foreign_keys f
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    fc.parent_object_id,parent_column_id,fc.referenced_object_id ,fc.referenced_column_id
                      FROM      sys.foreign_key_columns fc
                      WHERE     fc.constraint_object_id = f.object_id
                      ORDER BY  constraint_column_id
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ) t ( column_names )
)
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(f.parent_object_id)) + '.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id)) +' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(f.name)+';' AS DropStatement
FROM fkeys f
WHERE f.RowNum >= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

For a 100 tables it is not an option, but if you have just a few tables, create a diagram in SQL Server Management Studio, add your tables there and delete the dupes visually.